# PHP File Uploading Issue

Tags: php, file

I'm currently developing a website where users can upload their music. You can set various genres to display. Now, the problem is that sometimes (no idea why) the upload fails for certain files. An error doesnt get displayed. It's definitely not a permission error, since the uploading works for most files.
I've looked around a lot here already and tried many things, but nothing worked for me.
Here's my code:

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="musicupload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Choose an MP3 or WAV file<file></file>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" required>
    <br /><br />
    <fieldset>
        Genre
        <br />
        <input type="radio" id="db" name="Genre" value="Dubstep" required checked>
        <label for="db"> Dubstep</label>
        <input type="radio" id="trap" name="Genre" value="Trap" required>
        <label for="trap"> Trap</label>
        <input type="radio" id="BB" name="Genre" value="Bass Boosted" required>
        <label for="bb"> Bass Boosted</label>
        <input type="radio" id="other" name="Genre" value="Other" required>
        <label for="other"> Other</label>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Song" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Marc
 * Date: 04.12.2017
 * Time: 20:07
 */
require 'db.php';

$target_dir = "uploadedmusic/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$filename=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$genre = $_POST["Genre"];
$successfull = false;

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    // Check extensions
    if ($ext != "mp3" && $ext != "wav") {
        echo "Sorry, only MP3 & WAV files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $hash = md5_file("uploadedmusic/".$filename);
            //echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `music` (`id`, `filename`, `genre`, `uploaded`, `hash`) VALUES (NULL, '$filename', '$genre', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$hash')";
            $conn->query($sql);
            $successfull = true;
        } else {
            $successfull = false;
        }
    }
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Music</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">
     <img src="logo.png">
<h1>Please wait...</h1>
<p style="font-size: 35px;">
    <?php
    if ($successfull == true) {
        echo "Successfully uploaded ". basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])."! Use the search to find it!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. Check for potential invalid characters like () or - in your filename!";
    }


    ?>
</p>
    <a style="font-size: 35px" href="main.php">Start listening!</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check file upload size limit

Comment: Its set to 16 MB.

Comment: Check the file size before uploading and enable errors to see what is causing issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings

Comment: PHP with error_reporting( E_ALL ); doesn't give any errors, however the file size is 0 for mp3 files. Everything seems to work with WAV files.

Comment: Check the size of mp3 file on your system  ( before upload)

Comment: The file is a completely normal mp3 file. I can play it without issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160638/discussion-between-ravinder-reddy-and-private-ger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to see file upload errors to find the exact issue.

```
echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] // this will give you the error code.
```

Possible errors are. check this link http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

```
$phpFileUploadErrors = array(
    0 => 'There is no error, the file uploaded with success',
    1 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini',
    2 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form',
    3 => 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded',
    4 => 'No file was uploaded',
    6 => 'Missing a temporary folder',
    7 => 'Failed to write file to disk.',
    8 => 'A PHP extension stopped the file upload.',
);
```

Also in your code apart from checking extension, you need add condition to check upload errors

```
if ($uploadOk == 0 || $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"]!== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
   // if everything is ok, try to upload file
}
```